# Javascript: Setting specific element attributes to false in an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I use following code to reset a deleted flag:

```
for( var prefix in $42.words ) {
    var words = $42.words[prefix];  // words is an array of objects
    for( var j=0 ; j<words.length ; j++ ) $42.words[prefix][j].deleted = false;
}
```

The elements of the array are also objects.

Is it possible to implement this in a simpler or faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit faster, because there's only one lookup for `words.length` and no lookups for
`$42.words[prefix]` in the inner loop:

```
for( var prefix in $42.words ) {
    var words = $42.words[prefix];
    for( var j = words.length - 1; j >= 0; j-- ) words[j].deleted = false;
}
```

Comment: At first iteration you will attempt to set `words[words.length].deleted`, but `words[words.length]` will be undefined, so it will throw. Also note some browsers are optimized to iterate arrays forwards, so iterating backwards could be slower.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks, of course - 1, and a typo 0/= too. Fixed. Also thanks for information about browsers. I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

given some stub data. If I had an example of your data, that would be best:

```
var $42 = {};
$42.words = [{isOn:true, deleted:true},{isOn:true, deleted:true},{isOn:true, deleted:true}];

$42['words'].forEach(function(obj,i){
    obj.deleted = false;
});
```